# How to calculate average days in each step for elastic search aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 7.5.

I have an elastic search mapping that looks like this:

```
{
...
 "assigned_on" : { "type" : "date" },
 "collection_complete" : { "type" : "date" },
 "correct_complete" : { "type" : "date" },
 "production_complete" : { "type" : "date" },
 "complete_on" : { "type" : "date" }
...
}
```

Each of the properties are dates which are set when that step in the process completes. So the `assigned_on` signals the start of the process, and `collection_complete` will signify the end of the first step of the process.

Thus the difference between each date is the time that lapsed while that step was taking place. For example, the difference between `collection_complete` and `correct_complete` is the  amount of time the "correct" step took for that particular document.

This is what I have currently tried:

```
{
  "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
        "aggs" : {
            "average_step_durations" : {
                "aggs" : {
                    "collection_average_duration" : {
                        "avg" : { "script" : "doc['collection_complete'] - doc['assigned_on']" }
                    },
                    "correction_average_duration" : {
                        "avg" : { "script" : "doc['correct_complete'] - doc['collection_complete']" }
                    },
                    "production_average_duration" : {
                        "avg" : { "script" : "doc['production_complete'] - doc['correct_complete']" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**How do I aggregate the average numbers of days each step takes?** This is an example of what I'm wanting my output to look like:

```
   "_shards": ...,
   "hits": ...,
   "aggregations": {
      "average_step_durations": {
         "collection_stage" : 23.45,
         "correct_stage" : 3.89,
         "production_stage" : 4.51 // All these values would be in unit of days. 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in one aggregation , you need aggregation for every field for calculate average. and for desired output you need script .

Comment: @ARMAN, ok how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*bucket_script* will come in handy here.

Also, note that:

```
avg(col1 - col2) = avg(col1) - avg(col2)
```

Let's go step by step.

Mapping:

```
PUT /process_times
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "step1": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "step2": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Put some dummy values in there:

```
POST /process_times/_doc?refresh=wait_for
{
    "step1" : 0,
    "step2" : 120
}
```

Values: (10,20), (20,20), (0,120)

Query:

```
POST /process_times/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "terms": {
        "script":"'Hack, as only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at the top level'"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_step1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "step1"
          }
        },
        "avg_step2": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "step2"
          }
        },
        "avg_s2_to_s1": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "step1Avg": "avg_step1",
              "step2Avg": "avg_step2"
            },
            "script": "params.step2Avg - params.step1Avg"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "result" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Hack, as only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at the top level",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "avg_step2" : {
            "value" : 53.333333333333336,
            "value_as_string" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.053Z"
          },
          "avg_step1" : {
            "value" : 10.0,
            "value_as_string" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.010Z"
          },
          "avg_s2_to_s1" : {
            "value" : 43.333333333333336
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can iterate for multiple steps in the *process* collection.

Comment: Thank you for including this `avg(col1 - col2) = avg(col1) - avg(col2)`...That was first thought, so I'm glad you brought that to my attention.